# Не распечатывается файл javax.print

Tags: java

```
public class Class3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
        DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("example.txt");
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attrib = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attrib.add(new Copies(1));
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, docFlavor, null);
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printService.createPrintJob();
        docPrintJob.print(doc, attrib);
    }
}
```

пытаюсь распечатать файл, все отрабатывает без ошибок, `Process finished with exit code 0` но **файл не распечатывается**.
 принтер рабочий, стандартными средствами windows файл распечатывается.
Просмотрел весь интернет, скопипастил много примеров, результат один.

В чем может быть проблема?